# Intern Runner Test Results Not Showing Browser Info

Tags: intern, browserstack

Please bear with me as I am new at this. I am using Intern Runner to run functional tests on BrowserStack. In the terminal or when using a reporter to output to a file it is not showing the browser information in the test results. I have the browsers configured in the configuration file in the environments section. The test results just say any browser on any platform. On the BrowserStack site it shows the browser names, versions, OS, etc. I have tried the same tests on SauceLabs and the results show the browser names in the terminal and file output. Does anyone know of a way to get the browser info to display in the test results?

```
environments: [
    {
        browser: 'Chrome', browser_version: '44.0', os: 'OS X', os_version:
            'Yosemite'
    },
    {
        browser: 'Firefox', browser_version: '40.0', os: 'Windows',
        os_version: 'XP'
    },
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `os` and `os_version` are proprietary BrowserStack capabilities. The standard Selenium properties are named `platform` and `platformVersion`. Intern uses the standard properties when deciding how to output the name of the environment. If you want to submit a patch to Intern that alternatively uses the proprietary BrowserStack properties when forming the name of the environment, that would be OK, but the better thing would be to use the standard properties (and complain to BrowserStack if they aren’t supported on their platform).